# Using Sed in a for loop with a regular expression

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to modify a json file using a for loop to loop over a list of sample names and use sed to fix those sample names. Right now a subset of the input file is;

```
      "WA82671",
        "WA8267-technical-replicate-1":"AGCGTTGAT+CACATGTCC",
        "WA8267-technical-replicate-2":"TCATGGTCAAT+TGCAGTGAGC"
    "WA82671":{ "/scratch/jjz86252/ipyrad/3RAD_processed/WA8267_R1_1.fq.gz",
                "/scratch/jjz86252/ipyrad/3RAD_processed/WA8267_R2_1.fq.gz"
        "name":"WA82671",
```

I would like it to be;

```
      "WA8267",
        "WA8267-technical-replicate-1":"AGCGTTGAT+CACATGTCC",
        "WA8267-technical-replicate-2":"TCATGGTCAAT+TGCAGTGAGC"
    "WA8267":{"/scratch/jjz86252/ipyrad/3RAD_processed/WA8267_R1_1.fq.gz", 
              "/scratch/jjz86252/ipyrad/3RAD_processed/WA8267_R2_1.fq.gz"
        "name":"WA8267",
```

I have tried the follwing command;
for i in $(cat samplenames); do sed -er 's/$i\1/$i/g' names; done 
Howvever, this command fails to make any changes. It simply prints the entire file for each value of i.

Comment: use `sed --in-place` to make edits to the file once you're sure that what it's changing is what you want.

Comment: Making a backup of your original file first is a good idea too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using file paths that have the / forward slash, you should use commas in your sed expression. Something like...

```
for name in $(cat samplenames); do
    sed -e "s,${name}1,${name},g" sample --in-place
done
```